# ClassNotFoundException: org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

When trying to start a Spring Boot application with `mvn spring-boot:run` I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback
```

Indeed that class doesn't exist, but `org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.Callback` does. I'm trying to figure how how the class with the wrong name is being accessed, but there's not a single line of code in my project that refers to Flyway, only some configuration.

Any ideas?

The full error looks like this:

```
> mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------< com.example:projectxserver >--------------------
[INFO] Building projectxserver 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ projectxserver >>>
[WARNING] The artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final has been relocated to org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ projectxserver ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 15 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ projectxserver ---
[WARNING] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING] * Required filename-based automodules detected: [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar, javax.inject-1.jar]. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository! *
[WARNING] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ projectxserver ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ projectxserver ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ projectxserver <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ projectxserver ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2019-09-27 07:43:50.527  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] t.f.d.projectxServerApplication           : Starting projectxServerApplication on Utopia-Planitia with PID 7688 (C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\projectx\code\projectxserver\target\classes started by pupeno in C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\projectx\code\projectxserver)
2019-09-27 07:43:50.527  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] t.f.d.projectxServerApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-27 07:43:50.596  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-09-27 07:43:50.596  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-09-27 07:43:52.436  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-27 07:43:52.621  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 185ms. Found 4 repository interfaces.
2019-09-27 07:43:53.176  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd11f40a] is not eligible for getting processed by
all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-09-27 07:43:54.370  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-09-27 07:43:54.424  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-27 07:43:54.425  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.26]
2019-09-27 07:43:54.785  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-27 07:43:54.786  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4190 ms
2019-09-27 07:43:55.569  WARN 7688 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfigurati
on': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback not present
2019-09-27 07:43:55.575  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-09-27 07:43:55.597  INFO 7688 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-27 07:43:55.610 ERROR 7688 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback not present
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:528) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
        at com.example.projectxserver.projectxServerApplication.main(projectxServerApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback not present
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.computeParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:111) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:87) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:283) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getGenericParameterTypes(Constructor.java:281) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getGenericParameterType(MethodParameter.java:437) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper$MethodParameterTypeProvider.getType(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:291) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.SerializableTypeWrapper.forTypeProvider(SerializableTypeWrapper.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forType(ResolvableType.java:1401) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1309) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forMethodParameter(ResolvableType.java:1275) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.getResolvableType(DependencyDescriptor.java:316) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.checkGenericTypeMatch(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:77) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(GenericTypeAwareAutowireCandidateResolver.java:69) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.isAutowireCandidate(QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:147) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.isAutowireCandidate(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1430) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:415) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
        ... 62 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.202 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-27T07:43:55+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried downgrading to Flyway 5 and I get a different error, so, I'm focusing on getting Flyway 6 to work:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.3</version>-->
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.8:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Here's the full `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectxserver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-new-relic-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>newrelic-agent</artifactId>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>newrelic-agent.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin> <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093236/whats-going-on-here-execution-default-test-of-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsma -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
<!--                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>-->
                    <configuration>
<!--                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>-->
<!--                        <forkCount>3</forkCount>-->
<!--                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>-->
<!--                        <argLine>-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m</argLine>-->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>projectx</id>
            <url>https://mymavenrepo.com/repo/qSBXT4LNFS22Ie2EixnI/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectxcommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet.descriptor</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.8.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.63</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.26</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet.descriptor</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.1.3</version>-->
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>newrelic-agent</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What version of Flyway are you using? There were a couple of problems with Flyway 6.0 and v2.1.7 of Spring Boot.

Comment: @Ambro-r: I'm using Flyway 6.0.4 and Spring Boot 2.1.8. I added the details to the question.

Comment: Post your full pom.xml pls

Comment: If you are using `Spring boot` no need to specify version for such dependecies like Flyway which are supported by `Spring boot` and the correct version is specified in the Spring boot parent pom.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf: done, it's now in the question.

Comment: @pupeno : I am facing this same issue. Can you pls tel me after you removed the version, which version of Flywaydb was being fetched by SpringBoot?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just add Flyway Migration dependency to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
  <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

See [this](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot) doc on Spring Boot and Flyway integration.

Note that you do not need to provide a version for the dependency in your build configuration, as Spring Boot [manages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-dependency-management) that for you.

Comment: I already had the dependency, but removing a version specification did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: In my multi module project I had to remove the whole entry from `<dependencyManagement>` section of the root module and just leave the dep in the using module as shown above.

Comment: I also had the same issue of the dependency complaining about a missing `FlywayCallback not present` after I upgraded the version from `5.2.4` to the latest. After removing the version from the dependency, the issue was gone.

Comment: @Stephane I had the same error. Removing the version solved the problem but the warning "Flyway upgrade recommended: PostgreSQL 12.3 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested." remained. That's the problem.

Comment: @ka3ak I am curious, what IDE are you using? I wasn't able to get this to work in Spring Tool Suite. It complains that a version is needed and fails the build.

Comment: @linuxNoob I got this warning when I built from command line using Gradle. I solved it by upgrading the spring boot. See the question and the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685249/type-org-flywaydb-core-api-callback-flywaycallback-not-present

Comment: Hmm ok yeah, I'm using maven and am on 2.0.4.RELEASE version and can't update it to a higher version yet. I resolved by specifying the latest 5.x flyway version but I couldn't get the IDE to resolve it automatically. Not sure if it's a lacuna of the IDE or something else.

Comment: @linuxNoob The problem is that spring boot version < 2.2.2 refers to the class org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.Callback that doesn't exist in Flyway 6.5.0. So the simplest solution I see in this situation - upgrade of spring boot.

Comment: I have spring boot version 2.1.6, I placed above dependency but still have same issue. Can someone elaborate more? What is the other solution instead of upgrade version?

Comment: Got it!!! Spring version < 2.2.0 not compatible with Flyway version higher then 6.0.0 I change it to 5.2.4 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with the dependency itself. As suggested by Boris above, add flyway-core dependency and then make sure the dependency is properly downloaded.

It is better to refresh the dependencies list (gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies), before going to build.