# Type org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback not present

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

After upgrading Flyway from 5.2.4 to

```
compile group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '6.5.0'
```

and running the spring boot app I got the error:

```
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mapDao' parameter 0;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration':
Unexpected exception during bean creation;
nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException:
Type org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback not present
```

If I don't upgrade the app runs with a warning:

```
Flyway upgrade recommended: PostgreSQL 12.3 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested.
```

that I would like to solve

How should I configure the app so that it uses Flyway 6.5 and Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really answer the question but it's acceptable in my situation.
I've just updated Spring Boot dependency to 2.2.2 and the error has gone.
No changes in the app source code were needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.FlywayCallback` interface was replaced with `org.flywaydb.core.api.callback.Callback` in 2018, so just update your code to use the new interface.

Comment: There is no single line of code related to Flyway in the app source code. It seems that spring manages it.

Comment: I reduced the flyway version and everything worked for me